# SciPy SLSQP Claims Constraints Incompatible when Constraints are Compatible

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods

I have a constrained optimization problem where the objective function is convex under some inequality constraints over the input vector. The only issue is that SLSQP claims that the constraints are incompatible, which is untrue. I've checked both inequality constraints using the initial vector and they're both satisfied.

I understand that my objective function may be hard to optimize, but I thought that including the Jacobians for everything would help with this problem. It seems like there should be some step-size parameter I could tune in the the solver to fix this, but varying the tolerances for SLSQP didn't seem to fix the problem.

Below is a stripped down version of the code for one instance of the problem (in general many of these variables may change, including the dimension of the vector I am optimizing over), as well as the output it returns

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

###############################
# Problem Setup
###############################
omega = 2*np.pi/(1E-6)
r = 3.26

T = 1E-6/r
omega_s = 2*np.pi/T

yf = 120.E-6 
analytic_inf = 0.7611241494308488
analytic_inf_v = 43.30005226677565

n_vec = np.arange(1,4)
normalizing_vec = 1-n_vec**2*r**2

fqc_coeff = 7.422483151210897
fqc_mat = n_vec*omega_s/(1-(n_vec*r)**2)
fxd_mat = omega_s*n_vec

epsilon_coeff = 0.019552534524785916 
delta_coeff = 0.2015101389747311
alpha = 160.96016835831352

###############################
# Cost Function, Jacobians & Constraints
###############################
gaussian = lambda a: np.exp(-(fqc_coeff*(fqc_mat.dot(a)+omega_s/(2*np.pi))**2))
costa = lambda a: alpha*(1- gaussian(a))
costd = lambda a: delta_coeff*1/2*np.sum(a**2)
coste = lambda a: epsilon_coeff*1/2*np.sum((n_vec*2*np.pi*a)**2)

cost_f = lambda a: costa(a) + costd(a) + coste(a)

# Constraints
eqa = lambda a: (fqc_mat.dot(a) + omega_s/(2*np.pi))
ineqa = lambda a: eqa(a)*fqc_coeff + 1/np.sqrt(2)
jaca = lambda a: fqc_coeff*fqc_mat
ineqb = lambda a: -eqa(a)*fqc_coeff+ 1/np.sqrt(2)
jacb = lambda a: -fqc_coeff*fqc_mat
cons = [{'type':'ineq','fun':ineqa,'jac':jaca},
    {'type':'ineq','fun':ineqb,'jac':jacb}]

# Jacobian, if solver uses it
jacobian = lambda a: alpha*2*fqc_coeff**2*gaussian(a)*fqc_mat.dot(a)*fqc_mat + (
    delta_coeff*a) + (
    epsilon_coeff*(2*np.pi*n_vec)**2*a)

x0 = np.array([1.17120635, 0.54328102, 0.35740402])
result = minimize(cost_f, x0, method='SLSQP', jac=jacobian, 
    constraints=cons, options={'disp':True,'maxiter':1001,'ftol':1E-5})
print(ineqa(result.x))
print(ineqb(result.x))
```

And the output

```
Inequality constraints incompatible    (Exit mode 4)
            Current function value: 1.6377594465810514
            Iterations: 1
            Function evaluations: 1
            Gradient evaluations: 1
0.7431425286510408
0.6710710337220541
```

Comment: I've made some headway on the problem by rescaling all of the Jacobians and replacing the Gaussian by a quadratic, which holds to good approximation since I'm wanting solutions near the peak of the Gaussian, but I'd still be interested in a solution that resolves this problem more concretely.

Comment: Experiencing a similar problem with same error message although constraints respected. Did you solve this?

Comment: not yet, no. I am still interested in a solution

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the fortran code in the [scipy repository](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/dbd0128efed3413f94b4d180612179848d4070fe/scipy/optimize/slsqp/slsqp_optmz.f)

```
     IF (mode.EQ.6) THEN
          IF (n.EQ.meq) THEN
              mode = 4
          ENDIF
      ENDIF
```

And the comment `6: SINGULAR MATRIX C IN LSQ SUBPROBLEM`  seems there may be an issue with the LSQ subproblem.  I'm no expert in this area but you can take a look at section 2.2.3 of the seminal paper "A software package for sequential quadratic programming." by Dieter Kraft to see why a singularity is occurring.